# How I can prove refractive index in an environment is this?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

in "Applied Quantum Mechanics" by A.F.J. Levi, is a problem that I couldn't solve it can any solve it:
if electrical filed is:

$$
\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}, \omega \right) =\mathbf{E}_{0}\left(\omega \right)e^{ i \mathbf{k}\left(\omega \right)\cdot \mathbf{r}}=\mathbf{E}_{0}\left(\omega \right)e^{ i \left( k^{\prime}\left(\omega \right)+ik^{\prime\prime}\left(\omega \right) \right)\mathbf{k}^{\sim}\cdot \mathbf{r}}
\tag{1.97}
$$
and we have too,

$$
\mu_{r}=1,  \quad  \varepsilon\left(\omega \right)=  \varepsilon_{0} \varepsilon_{r}\left(\omega \right)=\varepsilon_{0}\bigl( \varepsilon^{\prime}_{r}\left(\omega \right) + i\varepsilon^{\prime \prime}_{r}\left(\omega \right)\bigr) 
$$

Now, how we can calculate refractive index?

for more info see snapshot image:
[image]

Comment: Essentially it's solved in main text  "Applied Quantum Mechanics" A.F.J. Levi , 2nd Ed. :  
\begin{align}
\nabla^{2}\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}, \omega \right) & =\dfrac{-\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}\;\varepsilon_{r}\left(\omega \right)\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}, \omega \right)
\tag{1.95}\\
\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}, \omega \right) &=\mathbf{E}_{0}\left(\omega \right)e^{ i \mathbf{k}\left(\omega \right)\cdot \mathbf{r}}=\mathbf{E}_{0}\left(\omega \right)e^{ i \left( k^{\prime}\left(\omega \right)+ik^{\prime\prime}\left(\omega \right) \right)\mathbf{k}^{\sim}\cdot \mathbf{r}}
\tag{1.97}
\end{align}

Comment: $$
n_{r}\left(\omega \right)=\sqrt{ \dfrac{1}{2}\biggl( \varepsilon^{\prime}_{r}\left(\omega \right) +\sqrt{ \varepsilon^{\prime 2}_{r}\left(\omega \right)+    \varepsilon^{\prime \prime 2}_{r}\left(\omega \right)} \biggr)}
\tag{1.98}
$$
Under equation (1.98) the author says : _"Equation (1.98) is obtained by substituting Eq. (1.97) into Eq. (1.95) and separating the
real and imaginary parts of the resulting expression."_  
**Are you trying this???**

Comment: it's not obvious for me can you more explain.i tested it but i couldn't prove it from these equation  thanks

Comment: Not sure how to help beyond what @Frobenius points out.   I suppose you must be making an algebra mistake somewhere, and that's something we can't help you with.  Be very careful; don't skip steps; make sure of each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :  A key to the solution is what is meant by the **complex wave 3-vector** $\:\mathbf{k}\:$. This vector is not any complex 3-vector in $\: \mathbb{C}^{3}\:$
$$
\mathbf{k} \ne \left(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3} \right)  \in \mathbb{C}^{3}, \:\:\text{that is with} \:\:  k_{\rho} \in \mathbb{C}
\tag{a-01}
$$
but
$$
\mathbf{k}=\left(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3} \right) =\bigl[k^{\prime}\left(\omega \right)+ik^{\prime\prime}\left(\omega\right)\bigr] \mathbf{k}^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}=\bigl[k^{\prime}\left(\omega \right)+ik^{\prime\prime}\left(\omega\right)\bigr]\left(k^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}_{1}, k^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}_{2}, k^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}_{3} \right)  \in \mathbb{C}^{3}
\tag{a-02}
$$
where  $\:\mathbf{k}^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}\:$  is a real 3-vector of unit norm 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{k}^{\boldsymbol{\sim}} & =\left(k^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}_{1}, k^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}_{2}, k^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}_{3} \right)  \in \mathbb{R}^{3}
\tag{a-03a}\\
\Vert \mathbf{k}^{\boldsymbol{\sim}} \Vert^{2} & =|k^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}_{1}| ^{2}+|k^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}_{2}| ^{2}+|k^{\boldsymbol{\sim}}_{3}| ^{2}=1
\tag{a-03b}
\end{align}
On the other hand, as author refers under equation (1.97) :  *"The ratio of  $\:k^{\prime}\left(\omega \right)\:$  in the medium and $\:k=\omega/c\:$  in free space is the refractive index."*

So we must find an expression for the refractive index defined by

$$
n_{r}\left(\omega \right) \equiv \dfrac{c k^{\prime}\left(\omega \right)}{\omega}
\tag{a-04}
$$
Now, starting with equations
\begin{align}
\nabla^{2}\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}, \omega \right) & =-\dfrac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}\;\varepsilon_{r}\left(\omega \right)\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}, \omega \right)
\tag{1.95}\\
\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}, \omega \right) &=\mathbf{E}_{0}\left(\omega \right)e^{ i \mathbf{k}\left(\omega \right)\cdot \mathbf{r}}=\mathbf{E}_{0}\left(\omega \right)e^{ i \left( k^{\prime}\left(\omega \right)+ik^{\prime\prime}\left(\omega \right) \right)\mathbf{k}^{\sim}\cdot \mathbf{r}}
\tag{1.97}
\end{align} 
by substituting Eq. (1.97) into Eq. (1.95) we have

$$
\nabla^{2}e^{ i \mathbf{k}\left(\omega \right)\cdot \mathbf{r}} =-\dfrac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}\;\varepsilon_{r}\left(\omega \right)e^{ i \mathbf{k}\left(\omega \right)\cdot \mathbf{r}}
\tag{a-05}
$$

Now, first
$$
\nabla e^{ i \mathbf{k}\left(\omega \right)\cdot \mathbf{r}} =i \mathbf{k}e^{ i \mathbf{k}\left(\omega \right)\cdot \mathbf{r}}
\tag{a-06}
$$
and then
$$
\nabla^{2} e^{ i \mathbf{k}\left(\omega \right)\cdot \mathbf{r}} =- \bigl[k^{\prime}\left(\omega \right)+ik^{\prime\prime}\left(\omega\right)\bigr]^{2}e^{ i \mathbf{k}\left(\omega \right)\cdot \mathbf{r}}
\tag{a-07}
$$
so
$$
\bigl[k^{\prime}\left(\omega \right)+ik^{\prime\prime}\left(\omega\right)\bigr]^{2}=\dfrac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}\;\varepsilon_{r}\left(\omega \right)=
\dfrac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}\;\bigl[\varepsilon^{\prime}_{r}\left(\omega \right) + i\varepsilon^{\prime \prime}_{r}\left(\omega \right)\bigr]
\tag{a-08}
$$
that is
$$
\bigl[k^{\prime 2}\left(\omega \right)-k^{\prime\prime 2}\left(\omega\right)\bigr]+i\bigl[2k^{\prime}\left(\omega \right)\cdot k^{\prime\prime }\left(\omega\right)\bigr]=\dfrac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}\bigl[\varepsilon^{\prime}_{r}\left(\omega \right)\bigr] + i\dfrac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}\bigl[\varepsilon^{\prime \prime}_{r}\left(\omega \right)\bigr]
\tag{a-09}
$$
Separating the real and imaginary parts  we reach the following quadratic equation with respect to  $\:n_{r}^{2}\left(\omega \right)$, see eq.(a-04)
$$
n_{r}^{4}-\varepsilon^{\prime}_{r}\;n_{r}^{2}-\dfrac{\varepsilon^{\prime \prime 2}_{r}}{4}=0
\tag{a-10}
$$
etc

Comment: i really thanks very much,you rescued me from 
Being confused

Comment: now i read and i written  on it,it is nice thanks very much

Comment: @stackprogramer For the future  : as you see on the top, your question is reasonably on hold and will be closed soon. This is due mainly to the fact that it's not  _"useful to the broader community, and to future users."_  But even if a homework-like question is useful, we must not post complete answers but hints. As you realize I violated this rule.